# Why is there a few pixels of white space margin at the bottom of position absolute divs

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have two boxes in the HTML

```
<div id="left" class="component">
</div>
<div id="game" class="component">
    <canvas id="game-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

One on the left, one on the right. Here is my CSS for positioning them:

```
.component {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

#game {
    left: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}

#game-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
  left: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

I also use the following CSS to get rid of any padding or margin

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/odgo22yb/2/

For some reason though there is an unexpected vertical scrollbar.

When you scroll down there is a few pixels of white space / margin on the bottom of the two boxes.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbar is caused by the canvas, to resolve the issue you need to add `display: block;`

```
#game-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

[**See jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/odgo22yb/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The white space on the bottom is caused by the canvas. You can either removed it or simply put `display: block` on `#game-canvas` to fix it. Check the snippet codes below.

```css
    * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .component {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #game {
        left: 50%;
        background-color: black;
    }

    #game-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    #left {
        left: 0px;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div id="left" class="component">
    Why is there a scrollbar and a few pixels of white space at the bottom of both divs?
</div>

<div id="game" class="component">
    <canvas id="game-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```